# Strip special characters and +1 from phone number

Tags: php, regex, phone-number

I've been trying to validate phone numbers to the format *5555555555*. I've successfully been able to strip the phone number of all special characters, but if a phone number is entered with +15555555555, the number still contains '1' at the beginning of the number. Is there anyway to remove both the +1 and special characters?

My current regex is `preg_replace('/^1|\D/', "", +15555555555);`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `str_replace('+1', '', $number);` --- but on the other hand the +{countrycode}{number} format is the international telecommunications union's standardization recommendation -
- [E.164](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) standard so maybe keep it?

Comment: Well, I wanted to keep the numbers 10 digits for integrity's sake. I might end up doing that though. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression for this.

```
str_replace('+1', '', $string)
```

will do it. However to explain why your regex currently fails, your string doesn't start with `1`, it starts with `+1` so `^1` is not a match.

Demo of current usage: https://regex101.com/r/kwwp1r/1/

Demo of a possible regex solution: https://regex101.com/r/kwwp1r/2/

```
^\+1
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Let's say someone entered 15555555555, is there a single regex, or str_replace method I could use to check against both "+1", and "1" at the beginning of the number?

Comment: Yes, `^\+?1` would make the `+` optional. Is it a rule that a phone number can't start with a `1`?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the +1 from it

```
$phone_num = "+15555555555";

$phone_num = preg_replace('/\+1/','',$phone_num);

echo $phone_num;
```

or you could use str_replace('+1','',$phone_num),  either or. I always use preg_replace out of habit.